# Result is always null in renderHook using React query and RTL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query

I am writing a test case for a component.

```
import { render, screen, waitFor, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";

describe("renders the Information component", () => {
  test("check the loading state", async () => {
    const team = "Test";

    const queryClient = new QueryClient();

    const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <MemoryRouter>
          <UserContext.Provider value={team}>
            <Information />
          </UserContext.Provider>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    );

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useInfo(), {
      wrapper,
    });

    console.log(result);

    expect(screen.getByText("Loading info...")).toBeInTheDocument();

    // Wait for the loading state to resolve
    await waitFor(() => {
      console.log(result);
      expect(
        screen.queryByText("Loading info...")
      ).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});

const getInfo = async () => {
  const url = generateApiUrl(ENDPOINTS.GET_INFO, true);
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(response) => prints the data when I execute test case
  return response?.data;
};
```

Hook :

```
export const useInfo= () =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ["info"],
    queryFn: () => getInfo(),
  });
```

Here, when I have added the log into the `getInfo` function, then it returns the data at that place. But when I am trying to use the `result` of the `userenderHook` their I am not able to get the data.  I am getting `{ result : null }`.

What can I try next?

Comment: It seems like the issue might be related to the asynchronous nature of useQuery and renderHook. The renderHook function from @testing-library/react-hooks returns the result of the hook immediately, which might not have resolved by the time you're checking it.

You can use the waitFor utility from @testing-library/react to wait for the hook to finish executing before checking its result.

Comment: @Coder I have also added the log inside the wiatfor , there also I am getting null

Comment: don't wrap the renderHook in waitFor, that it is for (you could wrap it in async act and await that, but I don't think that will help here either).

Comment: Are you missing imports, I don't see Information defined anywhere (nor useInfo imported in the testFile) . It looks weird to me that Information appears to be a component and you seem to be trying to wrap your hook with that component, which seems wrong. What do you want to do with the hook? If you are testing the hook, I don't think you should have to render the component. If you are testing the component, you can just mock the hook. I think you have the tests mixed together which makes it more complex and that is causing your issues.